# Proof: floor function is not differentiable at 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $f(x)=[x]$ , show that $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $c=0$, 
 Here's my work so far:

1.$\frac {df(c)}{dx}=\lim_{x \to c}\frac {f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$, $c=0$

2.$\frac {df(0)}{dx}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$, since $f(0)=0$

3.$\frac {df(0)}{dx}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {f(x)}{x}$

4.$\frac {df(0)}{dx}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {[x]}{x}$, use one-sided limit

5.$\frac {df(0)}{dx}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac {[x]}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac {0}{x}=0$

6.$\frac {df(0)}{dx}=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac {[x]}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac {-1}{x}= \infty$

Since one-sided limits are not equal, therefore

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {[x]}{x}$  doesn't  exist, and the function is not differentiable at $c=0$.

Q1\ Is this approach correct for proving? If there are any mistakes please let me know.

Q2\ at step 6. , The limit from left side as c approaches 0 is equal to infinity, which is not what it shows on a graphing calculator(see attached picture). instead according to the graph, limit of the derivative from left side is 0, and it actually makes more sense to me since the function $f(x)$ on interval $0>x≥-1$ is just a horizontal line and the derivative should be $0$ around $x=0$ and not differentiable at $x=0$ itself, is the graphing calculator wrong or my calculation are wrong?

Please note this is not a homework problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtRfM.jpg

Comment: Your proof looks fine, but it misses something big: The floor function is not even *continuous* at $x=0$, let alone differentiable.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is correct.

What the calculator shows is also correct. Indeed, the derivative at $x=-\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a very small positive number, is $\lim_{x\rightarrow \epsilon} \frac{f(x)-f(\epsilon)}{x-\epsilon} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \epsilon}\frac{-1 - (-1)}{x-\epsilon} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \epsilon}\frac{0}{x-\epsilon} = 0$.

The fact that the left derivative at $x=0$ is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} -\frac{1}{x}$ (and, therefore, infinite, as you said) does not imply that the value of the derivative behaves like $-\frac{1}{x}$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Thanks it's much clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Before testing for the equality of the two one-sided derivatives, should you not first check whether $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$?

The blue graph in the image is the graph of $f'(x)$, not of $- 1 / x$, for $x \in (- 1, 0)$.

Comment: I'm well aware of the discontinuity at x=0 , my only confusion was the derivative from the the left didn't equal to what the graph showed

Comment: At a point of discontinuity a "the derivative from the left" is a meaningless concept.  There is no such thing.  You can calculate the expression $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\infty$ but that limit is not a derivative and has no relevance to the behavior of the graph.  It's just a observation that the function is discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** You could just say "since $f$ is not continuous at $c=0$, then $f$ is not differentiable at $c=0$".

**(2)** Both graphing calculator and your calculation are correct. In some sense, the derivative of a function measures how much this function varies. Take a neighborhood of $c=0$, say $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ for an arbitrarily small $\epsilon >0$ and note that the variation of $f$ in this neighborhood is always $1$. Therefore, the rate of change is as bigger as you want.

Another way to see this is the following: define a sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 2}$ of functions on $(-1,1)$ by
$$f_n(x)=
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
-1 & x\in (-1,-\frac1n] \\
\frac12 (nx-1) & x\in (-\frac1n,\frac1n)\\
0 & x\in [\frac1n,1)
\end{array}\right.$$
Note that
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ and that the rate of change of each $f_n$ is $n$ (on $[0,1/n]$), so it's grow up as much as you want. Maybe, look at the derivatives
$$f'_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & x\in (-1,-\frac1n]\cup[\frac1n,1) \\
\frac12n & x\in (-\frac1n,\frac1n)
\end{array}\right. $$
and think about $f'(x)$ as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f'_n(x)$.

Ps.: Thinking about $f'$ like this isn't rigorous enough.

Comment: Then why can't we see this big rate of change on the graph?

Comment: Please, look at my answer now that I edited it.

Comment: Thanks for the effort it's well explained